# Reducing a set of predicate functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, reducers

I have an array of predicates coming into a function we'll call `searchForAcceptableNumber`.

```
searchForAcceptableNumber(arrayOfNumbers: number[], ...isNumberAcceptablePredicates: Array<(aNumber: number) => boolean>): number[] {
    const acceptableNumbers: number[] = [];

    const isNumberAcceptablePredicate: (aNumber: number) => boolean = (aNumber: number) => {
        const isLabelAcceptableReducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator && currentValue(aNumber);
        return isNumberAcceptablePredicates.reduce(isLabelAcceptableReducer);
    };

    arrayOfNumbers.forEach((aNumber: number) => {
        if (isNumberAcceptablePredicate(aNumber)) {
            acceptableNumbers.push(aNumber);
        }
    });
    return acceptableNumbers;
}
```

You get the idea. In essence it iterates through, everything works great... aside from the fact that `isNumberAcceptablePredicate` keeps getting an error of being type `(aNumber: number) => (aNumber: number) => boolean`. I can just get rid of the type and it will all compile and work just fine. Strange thing, if I hover over the `isNumberAcceptablePredicate` during a debug session, it says it is indeed of type `(aNumber: number) => boolean`.

This isn't necessarily code-breaking, that said, I end up passing this predicate over to other functions that need type `(aNumber: number) => boolean`, so it does introduce code-breaks with this added restraint. I'm sure I'm missing something absurd, I just can't tell what.

Comment: Just pass in a initial value to `reduce`: `return isNumberAcceptablePredicates.reduce(isLabelAcceptableReducer, true);` so that if the array `isNumberAcceptablePredicates` contains one element (function), the result will be `true` (a boolean) instead of the (only) function in the array.

Comment: Bless you, kind stranger.

Comment: BTW, you can use `filter` instead of `forEach` for the actual filtering: `return arrayOfNumbers.filter((aNumber: number) => isNumberAcceptablePredicate(aNumber));`. That way you won't need the array `acceptableNumbers`

Comment: I'll do one better: `arrayOfNumbers.filter((aNumber) => isNumberAcceptablePredicates.every((pred) => pred(aNumber)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide an initial value to the reduce function otherwise it defaults to using the first element in the array as the initial value which has type `(aNumber: number) => boolean` instead of `boolean`

```
function searchForAcceptableNumber(
  arrayOfNumbers: number[],
  ...isNumberAcceptablePredicates: Array<(aNumber: number) => boolean>
): number[] {
  const acceptableNumbers: number[] = []

  const isNumberAcceptablePredicate: (aNumber: number) => boolean = (
    aNumber: number,
  ) => {
    const isLabelAcceptableReducer = (accumulator, currentValue) =>
      accumulator && currentValue(aNumber)
    return isNumberAcceptablePredicates.reduce(isLabelAcceptableReducer, true) // <-- initialise to true
  }

  arrayOfNumbers.forEach((aNumber: number) => {
    if (isNumberAcceptablePredicate(aNumber)) {
      acceptableNumbers.push(aNumber)
    }
  })
  return acceptableNumbers
}
```

You could also greatly shorten this function using some built in array functions like so

```
function searchForAcceptableNumber(
  arrayOfNumbers: number[],
  ...isNumberAcceptablePredicates: Array<(aNumber: number) => boolean>
): number[] {
  return arrayOfNumbers.filter(number =>
    isNumberAcceptablePredicates.every(predicate => predicate(number)),
  )
}
```

And if you want to generalise the implementation you may do the following

```
function filterList<T>(
  values: T[],
  predicates: Array<(val: T) => boolean>,
): T[] {
  return values.filter(val => predicates.every(pred => pred(val)))
}
```

You could also use an arrow function since the function is only returning a value, some people prefer it for the terseness

```
const filterList = <T extends any>(
  values: T[],
  predicates: Array<(val: T) => boolean>,
): T[] => values.filter(val => predicates.every(pred => pred(val)))
```

Note: The reason for `<T extends any>` even though the `extends any` is semantically redundant, it is necessary because `<T>` alone is syntactically ambiguous and may be treated as a `JSX` tag